# Como cargar archivos desde el JAR

Tags: java, netbeans, imagen, jar

Hola amigos tengo un código de un programa que cambia la ventana de colores y tiene 3 botones con un icono o imagen pero la verdad que no entiendo porque en el JAR no me aparecen las imágenes, tengo las imágenes en la carpeta src y en sources packages esta un paquete con  mis clases y el main y otro es default packages ahí están mis imágenes,en netbeans funciona perfectamente. Al descomprimir mi JAR si estan las imagenes pero al ejecutarlo nada! alguien que me ayude por favor.

Estas lineas son las encargadas de poner el icono en un botón, use la librería `swing.ImageIcon`:

```
AccionColor accionAmarillo=new AccionColor("Amarillo", new ImageIcon("src/amarillo.jpg"), Color.YELLOW);
AccionColor accionAzul=new AccionColor("Azul    ", new ImageIcon("src/azul.jpg"), Color.BLUE);
AccionColor accionRojo=new AccionColor("Rojo     ", new ImageIcon("src/rojo.jpg"), Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 3):

No puedes usar la ruta relativa por que tus imágenes están en el jar, y cuando usar la ruta relativa estás tomando la ruta del `work directory` o sea la ruta desde donde se ejecutó el jar, puedes verla imprimiendo `System.getProperty("user.dir")`.

Lo que tienes que hacer es usar el método `getResource`:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/amarillo.jpg"));
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, una pequeña corrección... como "src" no es un package, en el classpath el fichero estará en "amarillo.jpg" (package "raíz"). Y para que busque por ruta absoluta, hay que empezar la ruta por "/", si no lo haces así añade delante el `package` de la clase. Así que quedaría `getResource("/amarillo.jpg")`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas cargar un archivo contenido en un archivo .jar, se puede realizar de esta forma si necesitas un `BufferedReader`:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/amarillo.jpg"); 
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

o de esta forma si necesitas cargar el archivo dentro de un `ImageIcon`:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/amarillo.jpg"));
```

Ejemplo:

```
AccionColor accionAmarillo=new AccionColor("Amarillo", new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/amarillo.jpg")), Color.YELLOW);
```