# Problemas al ejecutar un .jar en otro ordenador

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports, ireport

El problema es que al ejecutar el .jar todo funciona correctamente menos al crear el reporte. La ruta del .jrmxl no creo que sea porque en mi pc funciona tanto estando el proyecto desde C: como estando en un lapiz USB.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Hola @Pelayo , Bienvenido a [StackOverflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com), te recomiendo un [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) por la pagina para poder ganar tu primera medalla, y ver [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para hacer un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y la comunidad acepte de buena forma tu pregunta

Comment: Debes tener en cuenta que un .jar es dependiente de java y su version corresponiente, asi que debes de instalar la misma version de java en la maquina que desees utilizarlo.

Comment: me pasa lo mismo, lo pudiste solucionar?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Como cargar archivos desde el JAR](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79675/como-cargar-archivos-desde-el-jar)