# Cargar un archivo usando una ruta relativa dentro del JAR

Tags: java, archivo, jar

Hace unos dias que tengo un problema con un sistema en Java que estoy haciendo, el problema esque a la hora de crear el JAR, no me guardar mis configuraciones en un archivo txt.
Esta es la variable donde guardo el archivo

```
public String directorioGlobalConfig = "../gafe//src//recursos//GlobalConfig.txt";
```

A la hora de correrlo en el CMD, me dice que el archivo no ha sido encontrado

Mientras yo corra el sistema en [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans), si funciona bien, pero a la hora de correrlo en JAR no encuentra los archivos.

Tambien probé abriendo el JAR con Winrar, y noto que la carpeta SRC no existe dentro del JAR, la coloque manualmente y sigue sin funcionar...

Comment: src nunca va a estar en un jar porque src es el código (source) y un jar es un compilado, en java generalmente se usan archivos con extensión ".properties". https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Comment: Estas poniendo una ruta relativa, por lo que puede ser que al momento de ejecutar el java -jar en el CMD este busque en la ruta relativa, prueba poniendo una ruta absoluta o ejecuntando el jar en el cmd desde donde sea accesible ese txt.

Comment: shop350 aun no me quedan claro los ejemplos, lo unico que yo necesito seria poder obtener el PATH de esos archivos, y listo con eso ya deberia funcionar.

Comment: Pon el txt fuera del jar (los dos en la misma carpeta), y sólo mándalo a llamar por nombre, sin ruta (GlobalConfig.txt).

Comment: Aun  no me funciona, aunque si funcionará creo que me daría error a la hora de crear el instalador, ya que todo debería estar contenido dentro del JAR

Comment: La carpeta src no debe de existir dentro del jar. Necesitas especificar en tu pregunta, de que tipo es el proyecto (o adjuntar una captura de el tab project), especificar si inicialmente creas el archivo en esa ruta o ya debería de estar allí, poner la línea en que lo lees. Con una línea de código es prácticamente imposible reproducir tu problema, al respecto te recomiendo leer el artículo [mcve].

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como cargar archivos desde el JAR](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79675/como-cargar-archivos-desde-el-jar)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema con directorios en archivos jar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/154795/problema-con-directorios-en-archivos-jar)

Answer (score -1):

Hola una solución sería que utilices la clase `java.io.File` y su método `mkdir()`, justo al inicializar el jar (en el main) de esta manera:

```
File directorio = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\config");

If(!directorio.exists()){
directorio.mkdir();
}
```

Esto creará un directorio desde el que es lanzada la aplicación. La primer vez lo crea y el resto de veces lo ignora, a menos que sea borrado, entonces lo crea otra vez. La ruta de tu archivo podría quedar así:

```
public String directorioGlobalConfig = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\config\\GlobalConfig.txt";
```

Si desea conocer mas acerca de la clase `java.io.File` revisa la [API](http://ttps://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html)

Answer (score -3):

Prueba de diferentes maneras, intenta revisar **netbeans** en la configuración para la ejecución de programas entonces deberías de encontrar alguna opción el cual especifique la ruta de carga del sistema de archivos, entonces eso es lo que tienes que usar cuando trabajas en el *entorno* `cmd`, probablemente tenga una predeterminada como `"C:\Users\user\"`.

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque tu respuesta es totalmente incorrecta.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2912)

Comment: No uso **netbeans** asi que supuse que a diferencia de otros entornos de código como **visual studio** que almacenan variables de configuración en archivos como `vs.json` o `config.json`, entonces quizás en el entorno de codificación que usa el usuario donde el programa establece la ruta de archivos deseada la encuentre e intente especificarla al momento de usar la consola de comando de Windows **`cmd`**.

Comment: la pregunta no es sobre netbeans, es sobre leer un archivo de texto dentro de un jar, por lo que usar rutas en el classpath no sirve de nada